# rails 4 - change root if user logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've tried to find a solution to this, and as almost everybody uses devise all answers I've found for this - is a solution for devise.

I've set up my own omniauth and created the def current_user in the applications_controller.

I'm wondering how I can change the root when a user is logged in. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 1):

You essentially have two options.  The first is to have a `before_action` that checks if the user is logged in when hitting the root path, and if they are, redirect them to another page (e.g.: user dashboard).  The second is to have your controller action that represents the root path conditionally render one view for logged out users, and another for logged in users.  I'd recommend the former option for the sake of simplicity.